# Replace column in data frames based on second data frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames. Want to match the contents of df1$v1 and df2$v2 where they match, replace corresponding  df2$v2 content with df1v2 content.

```
df1
v1 v2
1   a1
2   a2
3   a3

df2
v1  v2  v3 v4
c1   1  c3  c4
d1  2   d3  d4
e1  3   e3  e4
```

Looking for this final output.

```
df2
v1 v2 v3 v4
c1 a1 c3 c4
d1 a2 d3 d4
e1 a3 e3 e4
```

Comment: Try: `merge(df2,df1,by.x="v2",by.y="v1",all.x=TRUE)`

Comment: Surprisingly, if you want to `match` variables, use the `match` function which you could have found using `?match` - e.g.: `df2$v2 <- df1$v2[match(df2$v2,df1$v1)]` . `merge` is basically an extension of that logic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'merge'-solution fails in some cases, e.g. if df1$"v1" and df2$"v2" do not match everywhere:

```
df1 <- data.frame( v1 = c(1,2,3),
                   v2 = c("a1","a2","a3") )

df2 <- data.frame( v1 = c("c1","d1","e1"),
                   v2 = c(1,5,3),
                   v3 = c("c3","d3","e3"),
                   v4 = c("c4","d4","e4") )

out <- merge(df2, df1, by.x='v2', by.y='v1', all.x=T)
out <- out[,-1]

> out
  v1 v3 v4   v2
1 c1 c3 c4   a1
2 e1 e3 e4   a3
3 d1 d3 d4 <NA>
```

Another example, where df1$"v1" and df2$"v2" do match everywhere:

```
df1 <- data.frame( v1 = c(1,2,1),
                   v2 = c("a1","a2","a3") )

df2 <- data.frame( v1 = c("c1","d1","e1"),
                   v2 = c(1,2,1),
                   v3 = c("c3","d3","e3"),
                   v4 = c("c4","d4","e4") )

out <- merge(df2, df1, by.x='v2', by.y='v1', all.x=T)
out <- out[,-1]

> out
  v1 v3 v4 v2
1 c1 c3 c4 a1
2 c1 c3 c4 a3
3 e1 e3 e4 a1
4 e1 e3 e4 a3
5 d1 d3 d4 a2
```

The following solution is not very elegant, but it works in these examples:

```
f <- function( dF1, match1, data1,
               dF2, match2, data2  )
{
  if ( is.factor(dF1[,data1]) )
  {
    dF2[,data2] <- as.factor(dF2[,data2])
    levels(dF2[,data2]) <- c(levels(dF2[,data2]),levels(dF1[,data1])) 
  }     
  n <- which(dF1[,match1] == dF2[,match2])         
  dF2[n,data2] <- dF1[n,data1]    
  return( dF2 )
}

out <-f1( df1, "v1", "v2", df2, "v2", "v2" )
```

Example 1:

```
> out
  v1 v2 v3 v4
1 c1 a1 c3 c4
2 d1  5 d3 d4
3 e1 a3 e3 e4
```

Example 2:

```
> out
  v1 v2 v3 v4
1 c1 a1 c3 c4
2 d1 a2 d3 d4
3 e1 a3 e3 e4
```

If the rows where df1$v1 and df2$v2 do not match are not wanted in the output, they can be removed by the following modification:

```
f <- function( dF1, match1, data1,
               dF2, match2, data2  )
{
  if ( is.factor(dF1[,data1]) )
  {
    dF2[,data2] <- as.factor(dF2[,data2])
    levels(dF2[,data2]) <- c(levels(dF2[,data2]),levels(dF1[,data1])) 
  }     
  n <- which(dF1[,match1] == dF2[,match2])         
  dF2[n,data2] <- dF1[n,data1]    
  return( dF2[n,] )
}

out <-f1( df1, "v1", "v2", df2, "v2", "v2" )
```

Example 1:

```
> out
  v1 v2 v3 v4
1 c1 a1 c3 c4
3 e1 a3 e3 e4
```

In the 'merge'-solution this can be achieved by 'all.x=F', but Example 2 still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
out <- merge(df2, df1, by.x='v2', by.y='v1', all.x=T)
out <- out[, -1]
```

You'll get a complaint about column name 'v2' being duplicated in both tables, so you could use `suppressWarnings()` if you wanted, or rename the 'v2' column of `df1` to something not already in `df2`.

`merge` puts your merge column as the first one (the first 'v2' column being the numeric 1 2 3), hence the `out[, -1]` to remove it.

Comment: Lets say  names(df2) = "p1" "p2" "p3" "p4"

Comment: So - the function solution is more elegant actually, and it does the job - if the data frames are the same size.  If the data frame size is different, you get error.     Error in Ops.data.frame(dF1[, match1], dF2[, match2]) : 
  ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames